# Backing up files from an older Ipod (60G) - Photos are not being copied

Tags: backup, photos, ipod

My wife's computer died. Her ipod lives. It hadn't been used for some time It's an older 60G (thick case). I am trying to copy all files from the Ipod to the PC. I tried several programs, including a registered Touchcopy 11, and Gizmorip.I wish to copy MP3 files and image files.

I am able to copy the MP3 files. I am not able to copy the image files. When I try to copy, small image files that are about 10-15k get transferred, and are extremely low resolution. It is clear that the original image files are on the ipod, as I can see much more detail when viewed on the ipod itself, and when I (tentatively, as I don't want to accidentally mix Itunes libraries) attach the ipod to another computer running Itunes. Then, it shows 2.2 GB of photos.

I can keep trying various software, but it seems there is a more basic issue I am not understanding, and I will probably run into the same thing no matter the software.

What can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried putting the iPod in to disk mode and cooing the photos from the DCIM folder? Here's a link to goolge cache, the instructions are so old it 404s on apple.com   http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Jmj1Ubeg0KUJ:support.apple.com/kb/ht1363+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Thank you. I was able to place it in disk mode. I connected, and it showed up as a Drive D. However, there is no DCIM folder. There are a few nonrelevant folders, and there is a Photos folder. 

In the Photos folder, there is a 2,645 KB file named Photo Database, and a Thumbs subfolder. In the Thumbs subfolder are 7 files, each with an extension of .ithmb and of them 3 are 512,325 KB, while the others are 382,050 KB, 215,002 KB, 63,524 KB, and 6,997 KB.

Comment: I guess that was before Apple moved them to the DCIM folder. Sounds like you'll have to use a convertor to convert the ithmb files to jpg. Not sure why some are so big; maybe an ithmb file contains multiple jpgs/pngs? I can't recommend a program to do this in windows. The mac program would be File juicer.